# Combining columns of a datafame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm new to R and I was trying to combine the columns (x axis) of a dataframe together in R to get the sum in a single column.

```
Tourism      Weekdays        Weekends
Profit       100             20
Visitors     250             75
```

How would I be able to combine `Weekdays` and `Weekends` into a single column called `Week` so it would look like the one below? As I understand it is possible to do a row addition if I wanted to combine `Profit` and `Visitors` so my thought was there must be something similar for columns.

```
Tourism      Week 
Profit       120  
Visitors     325
```

Comment: `df$Week <- df$Weekdays + df$Weekends`

Answer (score 1):

Two possible approachs

### Data

```
df <-
  data.frame(
    Tourism = c("Profit","Visitors"),
    Weekdays = c(100,250),
    Weekends = c(20,75)
  )
```

### Base R

```
df$Week <- df$Weekdays + df$Weekends
```

### Tidyverse

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(Week = Weekdays + Weekends)
```

### Result

```
# A tibble: 2 x 4
  Tourism  Weekdays Weekends  Week
  <chr>       <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
1 Profit        100       20   120
2 Visitors      250       75   325
```